# NextJS query in getInitialProps behaves differently for encoded url params on production

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this encoded url: `keyword/pl%2Fsql` which is basically `keyword/pl/sql` so the keyword is `pl/sql`.

The I have a `getInitialProps` like this for the page:

```
Keyword.getInitialProps = async ({ query, res }) => {
    console.log(query);
    const keyword = query.keyword[0];
    ....
```

When using my local dev server `keyword` is `pl/sql` however on production I think it is splitting by the / again so keyword is only `pl` as i suspect `query.keyword` is now an array with pl and sql. (index 0 is pl and index 1 is sql).

The directory is defined like this `jobs/keyword/[...keyword].js`
Does anyone know why? Or what I can do?

Comment: I facing the same situation, I must convert the URL to keyword/pl/sql to get full query params.

Comment: My solution now is to do this: `keyword = query.keyword.join('/');`